# formatting string dates using javascript jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some dates which are written like this:

```
7-sep, 14-sep, 21-sep, 28-sep,

 5-oct,12-oct, 19-oct,26-oct,

2-nov, 9-nov, 16-nov, 23-nov,30-nov,

 7-dec,14-dec, 21-dec,28-dec-2013.
```

How can i format them so they look cleaner using javascript jQuery or even CSS? I would like them in a table, like this:

**DATES  | PRICE   |   NOTES**

Comment: Somehow i do not understand what do you want. Do you want a conversion like 14-sept to 7/14/2013?

Comment: 7-sep to 7th September 2013 in a table row.

Comment: So the input you have is exactly like what you have posted?

Comment: You need to convert them with `Date()`.

Comment: It looks crappy. I want the dates to be in a table for each row and also the lower case is a problem. I need to stop the end user being retarded!

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/CucaS/)

```
var d = new Date();
var arr =[];
var months = new Array('jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec');
var month = new Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
var x = "7-sep, 14-sep, 21-sep, 28-sep, 5-oct,12-oct, 19-oct,26-oct,2-nov, 9-nov, 16-nov, 23-nov,30-nov, 7-dec,14-dec, 21-dec,28-dec-2014";
var x_date = x.split(',');
$.each(x_date, function (i, val) {
    var dt = ($.trim(val)).split('-');
    var dt_new = new Date(months.indexOf(dt[1]) + 1 + ',' + dt[0] + ',' + d.getFullYear());
    var day = dt_new.getDate();
    var dt_new_ret = day + ([, 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][/1?.$/.exec(day)] || 'th') + ' ' + month[dt_new.getMonth()] + ' ' + dt_new.getFullYear();
    arr.push(dt_new_ret);
});
console.log(arr);
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/CucaS/1/)

```
$.each(arr, function (i, val) {
    $('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + val +
        '</td><td>Price Here</td><td>Note Here</td></tr>');
});
```

added this in the above code to add it to table

Comment: Nice! This is it. This is your solution @PriceCheaperton

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you'll need to process those dates somehow depending on the format you have them in. Assuming you have the dates as a string, you can "tokenize" it into an array to grab the dates separately. Then you can use a simple loop to create table rows.

```
var dates = "7-sep, 14-sep, 21-sep, 28-sep, 5-oct,12-oct, 19-oct,26-oct, 2-nov, 9-nov, 16-nov, 23-nov,30-nov, 7-dec,14-dec, 21-dec,28-dec-2013.";    
dates = dates.substring(0, dates.length - 1).replace(' ', '');
var datesArray = dates.split(',');
for (var i = 0; i < datesArray.length; i++) {
    $('tbody').append('<tr><td>' + datesArray[i] +
        '</td><td>Price Here</td><td>Note Here</td></tr>');
}
```

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/FuY38/

Answer (score 0):

check out moment.js at http://momentjs.com/

it's super compact and gives you a lot more flexibility than the regular methods on a Date object.

with moment.js you could do the following:

```
var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();
var d = moment('7-sep'+' '+current_year);
d.format("Do MMMM YYYY");
```

this returns "7th September 2013"